# bootstrap date picker blocking dates

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

i have used a date picker from bootstrap. I was wondering how would i exclude the 10 days from the selected day the user has clicked

for example the user chooses 10th April 2015. That user can only select dates from 10th April 2015 - 19th April 2015 which would be the ending date.

Here is my code for the date picker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var nowDate = new Date();
        var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
            $(function () {
                $('#startdate').datetimepicker({
                minDate:today,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'   
                }).change(function (selected) {
                var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                $('#enddate').datetimepicker('maxDate', startDate+10);
                });


                $('#enddate').datetimepicker({
                minDate:today,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'   
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option "enabledDates", disables selection of dates NOT in the array, perhaps that will work for you?

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enableddates